# How to execute all statement except one based on some condition?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

Let's say I have a method in which there are **multiple statements which will be executed when methods call except one**. (one statement which will not be executed will be decided based on parameter passed to the method).

how can I achieve above scenario?

Things I have done so far.

I have following method.

```
enum Abc
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2,
    D = 3,
    E = 4,
}
int GetSum(Abc abc)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if(abc != Abc.A)
    {
        sum += 23;
    }
    if(abc != Abc.B)
    {
        sum += 68;
    }
    if(abc != Abc.C)
    {
        sum += 96;
    }
    if(abc != Abc.D)
    {
        sum += 57;
    }
    if(abc != Abc.E)
    {
        sum += 63;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Here before adding value to `sum` I am checking whether I have to add or not based on the value of `abc`.

Basically, I want that if value of `abc` is `Abc.A` then execute all the statement except `sum += 23;`.

In my code there are too many if conditions. Is there way to do things with less if statement or any other way(better)?

**Note:-** Here `sum += //something` is just one of the statements, and it is not necessary that the statement is addition only (it will be anything).

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . What is your code trying to achieve?

Comment: Furthermore this seems like a good fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Apart from this you can use a [`switch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/06tc147t(v=vs.120))-keyword for this.

Comment: Is your example far away from your actual code? Or is it really some relatively simple computation without further sideeffects?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Dictionary` containing `Action` objects (the modern variant of delegates):

```
int GetSum(Abc abc)
{
    int sum = 0;
    var actionDict = new Dictionary<Abc, Action>
        {
            { Abc.A, () => sum += 23 },
            { Abc.B, () => sum += 68 },
            { Abc.C, () => sum += 96 },
            { Abc.D, () => sum += 57 },
            { Abc.E, () => sum += 63 }
        };

    foreach (var key in actionDict.Keys)
        if (key != abc) actionDict[key]();

    return sum;
}
```

Note that with a Dictionary, *the order of `.Keys` is not predictable*.

For a predictable order you'd need to use a collection of KeyValuePairs, as follows:

```
int GetSum(Abc abc)
{
    int sum = 0;
    var actions = new List<KeyValuePair<Abc, Action>>
    {
        KVP(Abc.A, () => sum += 23),
        KVP(Abc.B, () => sum += 68),
        KVP(Abc.C, () => sum += 96),
        KVP(Abc.D, () => sum += 57),
        KVP(Abc.E, () => sum += 63)
    };

    foreach (var action in actions)
        if (action.Key != abc) action.Value();

    return sum;
}

KeyValuePair<Abc, Action> KVP(Abc x, Action y)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<Abc, Action>(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Note that `List<KeyValuePair<Abc, Action>>` allow duplicates too.

Comment: `Action` isn't so much "the modern variant" of delegates, as it's one way to deal with delegates (if they match a particular signature)

Answer (score 1):

In general you're asking for sort of the reverse of a `switch` statement; which isn't a thing.  Also I would say that your statement of having "too many `if`s" is subjective; if this is the requirement, then what you have is a fairly straightforward way of implementing it, and I'd have to have a concrete reason to want a "more clever" (i.e. "harder to read") solution in its place.

But in the *specific* case you've listed, you could just reverse the logic and then use a regular `switch` statement.

```
int GetSum(Abc abc)
{    
    int sum = 307; //23 + 68 + 96 + 57 + 63
    switch (abc) {
        case Abc.A:
            sum -= 23;
            break;
        case Abc.B:
            sum -= 68;
            break;
        // etc.
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Obviously if the individual statements are more complex, such that you can't "start at the end" and reverse the logic - in particular if each statement has side effects - then this approach won't apply.  But then, in a more complex case, there may be some other pattern that makes more sense. (Including, quite possibly, just the run of `if` statements.)

Comment: What a coincident - Just totaled 307 on the calculator!

Comment: Since the values don't seem to be flags, I'd even just precompute an array and use the enum values as index.

Comment: @Fildor - Maybe.  Depends.  That would make it harder to update the code if one of the values were to change.  (With a pre-calculated array you'd have to change 5 or 6 things.  With a reverse-logic switch as I show above, 2 things.  With the original implementation OP doesn't want, only the 1 thing that *acutally* changed.)   That's what I mean about needing a reason to be clever, and that's why this question *may* be suffering from over-simplification (to the point of ruling out a more sophisticated design solution)

Comment: Absolutely agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer that @PeterB's, but only for your sum example:

```
int Method(Abc abc)
{
    Dictionary<Abc, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<Abc, int>()
    {
        { Abc.A, 23 },
        { Abc.B, 68 },
        { Abc.C, 96 },
        { Abc.D, 57 },
        { Abc.E, 63 }
    };

    return dictionary
        .Where(kvp => kvp.Key != abc)  // filter where Abc is different
        .Sum(kvp => kvp.Value);        // sum all values after filtering
}
```

@PeterB's answer is really great and gives easy modifications in your dictionary (new value, deleting or modifying one), or even change the work to do.
Mine just gives a "small" shortcut if you only want to sum your values.